# How do I set the preferred wireless network in Linux Mint 17?

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi

I'm currently in an environment with two wireless networks: `OrganizationFoo`, which is present pretty much everywhere I go, and `OrganizationFooSubset`, which is only present in a certain location.

When possible, I'd like to connect to `OrganizationFooSubset` because it's a faster, more reliable network. If this is out of range, I'd like to connect to `OrganizationFoo`.

[image: Network connections dialog]

How can I configure this from within Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon (64-bit)?

I've found the network connections configuration dialog, but there are no "Move Up" or "Move Down" buttons, and drag-and-drop has no effect. In the actual `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` directory, each connection gets its own file, and I don't see a master list where I could reorder them.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

I feel silly answering a 6 year old question, but the fix is easier now.
You can raise the connection priority for your preferred network by changing the general setting.

Comment: Hey, this is perfect! Thanks very much. Late for past-me, maybe, but just on time for present-me and many others!

Answer (score 5):

It seems that this has been a common request for at least the last five years, but [progress](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=580018) is slow.

You could always ditch Network Manager and manually control your Wi-Fi network by configuring `wpa_supplicant` to priorotise your network.  Details [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic), but it seems a lot of work.  It would also mean manually scanning for and configuring each new network you come across.

Comment: A fix was allegedly merged into master in Oct 2014, but I still don't see a mechanism in Mint 18 / Cinnamon to order networks.

Answer (score 3):

You could untick the automatic connection option under the 'General' tab of `OrganizationFoo`, so it would only automatically connect to other Networks including `OrganizationFooSubSet` - the problem here is that it won't connect to `OrganizationFoo` automatically when it is available, you will have to do that manually.

[image]